# Can I intercept function calls in my code only in designated files?

Tags: c

I have two (very long) c code files, `foo1.c` and `foo2.c`, and a library which I don't have access to its source code `libfoo.a`. In all three files, they use a function called `MyFooFunc`. Now I just want to intercept `MyFooFunc` calls from `foo1.c`, have my own implementation, but do not intercept the function calls in the other two files. Is there any way I can do that, without rename the `MyFooFunc` function name?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes it is possible and you would have to check the return address. The files/their names are irrelevant once compiled. You would need to perform a check on the stack pointer to see where the call is coming from to intercept it. There are several ways to do this, most common is hotpatching : replacing first x bytes with jump instruction to your hook

Comment: Since you have `foo1.c`, you can simply insert `#define MyFooFunc MyAlternateFooFunc` in it.

Comment: Do you use GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change "foo1.c", the most simple way is to compile it wrapped in another source file. Don't compile it on its own then.

This wrapper changes the name of the function with a preprocessor macro, as Eric suggested.

```c
// foo1altered.c
#define MyFooFunc MyAlternateFooFunc
#include "foo1.c"
```